# Accessing c# property from unmanaged C++ using COM Interop

Tags: c#, c++, properties, com, interop

I have a property with return type string(or even object) which is exposed into COm as get_Name and put_Name in .tlh file. How to access this and set this property in unmanaged c++.
Till Now..
In C# side,
I have this property exposed through an interface with DispId(1) and implemented it in the class inheriting the interface.
In c++(unmanaged side),
I created a interface pointer with the following syntax:

```
ManagedDLL::ICalculatorPtr pICalculator;//Interface having the property
hr = pICalculator.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ManagedDLL::Calculator));//1. Calculator implements property of Icalculator & hr is of HRESULT type
    pICalculator->put_Name="New1";
    pICalculator->put_Name="New2";//below error comes here :
```

**error C2659: '=' : function as left operand** 
I know the meaning of this error. 
FYI: I want to raise an event in c# when my Name property is set in unmanaged c++.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pICalculator->put_Name(_TEXT("New1"));
```

Your C# properties became methods, after importing from COM.

**UPD**.
The sample uses `_TEXT` macro to convert from `char*` to `BSTR`, but there's also useful type [`CComBSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in ATL, which makes deals with `BSTR` much easier.

Comment: I knew that!. So i tried it too. but it expects BSTR. can you tell me how to convert char* to BSTR. I went to this link too.Saw various methods but in vain while implementing it. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/081d0d02-caa3-4700-9bef-7cbc248370af/visual-c-how-to-convert-const-char-to-bstr

Comment: _TEXT is a macro which substitutes what?coz surely it would give me an error undeclared identifier..right?I am New to COM.so spare me!

Comment: No, _TEXT does **not** generate a BSTR.  It belongs in a museum, SO answers should not use it anymore, even if it is used completely wrong.  Use SysAllocString() or a wrapper class.

Comment: @HansPassant: why so? Fortunately, I'm not a C++ guy for a long time, and I'm asking this just for curiosity.

Comment: It was used to generate 8-bit string literals in programs that needed to run on Windows 95, 98 or ME.  Nobody uses those anymore, all Windows versions in use are Unicode at their core.

Comment: @HansPassant SysAllocString is defined to take a parameter of type OLECHAR *. We're giving it a char *. These are not the same thing. So first of all we need to convert the char * into an OLECHAR *. I saw one macro A2OLE but couldn't see any example of using it!Any thoughts?

Comment: Lots of ways to convert an 8-bit string to Unicode.  Best thing to do is to stop using 8-bit strings in your code, Unicode runs the world today.  In your snippet, it just take L"New1" to specify a Unicode literal.

Comment: @HansPassant You need to make that comment into an answer.  That is the only way I was able to get this to work.  Everything else, from various casts to using macros, did not work.  This seems to be required when passing any kind of string from C++ to/from .NET through COM interop.